# KeyError when importing Excel file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I have an excel file with multiple sheets which is already imported by `pd.Read_Excel`. It is an `OrderedDict()`. Then I created an empty `OrderedDict()` and started a for loop to do some stuff as follows:

```
imp_by_xlfile=pd.ExcelFile(excelfile)
sheet_names=imp_by_xlfile.sheet_names

imported=pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_names, 
names=list(range(0,21)), usecols=list(range(0,21)))

newdf= OrderedDict()
for i in imported.keys():
    newdf[i]=e[i].dropna(how='all')

mdf= OrderedDict()
for i in sheet_names:
    if type(newdf[i].loc[12,7])==str:
        address=newdf[i].loc[12,7].split('-')
        address.append(None)
    elif math.isnan(newdf[i].loc[12,7]):
        address=[None,None]
    else:
        address=[None,None]
```

but at this line the following error is raised:

```
KeyError: '4'
```

I don't know even where should I look to debug this problem because everything is under the Pandas shell.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this code is _very_ confused. `OrderedDict` and `pandas` are so far removed... you're trying to call pandas methods on a pure python object

Comment: @roganjosh, Actually, I believe `pd.read_excel` returns `OrderedDict` in certain situations.. when you supply multiple worksheets, for example.

Comment: `but at this line the following error`. Please provide **full traceback**.